# Anybody know where I can find Visio stencils for Netgear products?

Tags: netgear, visio, networking

Their website says they can be found here:

http://www.netgear.com/Home/Landing/en-US/WW_VisioStencils.aspx

But in reality that simply redirects to their home page (excellent site management Netgear!).

Specifically I'm looking for stencils for the ProSafe FS108 and FS116 switches.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is where the link is supposed to lead:**

http://www.altimatech.com/ncpmfg/index.asp?mfgacronym=netg

**Open-source Google-fu:**

```
visio site:netgear.com
```

Answer (score 0):

No point following the link 'cos it is just for harvesting emails - when you click on the supplied link to download them it states it is expired - supposed to be valid for 24 hours and didn't work after less than 2 minutes.